# How click in Button with Selenium python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, selenium

I want to click the configuration button, which leads to discord profile information,

[image]

Guys, I want to click on the gear at the bottom, how can I do this?  This is my code:

```
option = Options()
option.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=option)
driver.get("https://discord.com/channels/395582581124497408/395582581124497412")       
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)              
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a.item'))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div#contents-18-Yxp"))).click()
```

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can click it with this code:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div'[aria-label="User settings"]').click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the ID of that button, then use `driver.find_element_by_id("ID").click()`
You should read this tutorial https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/click-element-method-selenium-python/

Answer (score 0):

First, you must get an identifier for your element, for example:

- class
- xpath
- css selector
- ... etc

then `drive.find_element_by_(class, xpath, ...)(string).click()`

Example:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('(//*[@class="contents-18-Yxp"])[7]')
```

this is the identifier for the settings section, you can copy it, note that this xpath can be changed if the discoed is updated, the solution is easy, just with the same way get the new xpath and paste it instead of the old one.

with the same Technique, find the user profile identifier, and paste it and remember `.click()`